# How to construct resource path without id in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

```
class A < ApplicationController
  def step1
   @b = B.new
  end

  def step2
  end
end
```

Step1 renders this form

```
<%= form_for @b do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :redirect_to=> url_path_to_controller_A_step2_and_include_id_of_resource_b_created_after_submitting_this_form
<% end %>
```

How do I generate the url_path_to_controller_A_step2_and_include_id_of_resource_b_created_after_submitting_this_form without knowing the id of the "to be create" resource B?

In my routes.rb file:

get "A/:b_id/step2", :controller=>:A, :action=>:step2, :as=>:A_step_2

I am sure I am not the first one facing this problem, but searches through google and over here, didn't throw up relevant results.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve by having redirect link in hidden field. The form when submitted will send data to some controller action, this action will save resource `b` and will know its id. You can `redirect_to` from the action.

Comment: It keeps controllers and actions loosely coupled. By having controller A's action tell controller B's action where to redirect to after it is done, I can also have another controller C do the same thing - include a hidden field with redirect parameter that tells it where to go after creating/saving. Controller A and controller B know nothing about each other with hidden fields...except that B knows there is a redirect parameter which has to be honored